# How to establish an ssh connection in a Lua script to execute a command on a remote server?

Tags: lua

I want to write a script in Lua for establishing an ssh connection to execute a command on a remote server

Can anyone give me a hint

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.execute ('ssh user@127.0.0.1')` to make the connection, but you may have to use `os.execute ('ssh user@127.0.0.1 &'..yourCommand)` to make it execute afterwards in the shell, but I'm not entirely certain that it would work. It maybe better to create the script in Bash and execute that from Lua. If you needed to run differing commands, then you could have the script receive arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As said by U319344, `os.execute` would be enough if you simply want to execute some program at the remote side.

If you need to interact with this program, you will need `io.popen` - it returns a file handle which you can use to read from and write to the remote command.

(And usually you will want to setup public-key authentication to not have to deal with passwords here.)

Comment: hi Eberman..im also trying out io.popen..if i stuck up with that i will contact u again..thank u for your info..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `io.popen` as others suggested. If you want more control, try [lpty](http://www.tset.de/lpty/).