# Simple encryption in lua

Tags: c, encryption, lua, luasocket

I was wondering, what would be the easiest way to encrypt a message, into a 128-bit with a key. I wanted to code something on my personal computer, that would use LuaSocket, and based on what is sent to my PC, the computer executes *X* command. This is just something easy, and something for me to code, so I can remotely access my computer, from another computer. I want to make the script first require a password, before granting access to ANY command. But, if someone is spying on the connection, they can take the password, and abuse my PC. So, is there a simple way to securely communicate between MY PC, and the PC that is connecting with my PC (dunno much about encryption)? (somewhat-off-topic: how do you get LuaSocket to reply to the client? lua.org explains client-to-server, but how do you do server-to-client?)

Comment: You seem to be describing ssh.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965062/how-to-establish-an-ssh-connection-in-a-lua-script-to-execute-a-command-on-a-rem

Comment: It is not a server. It is a Personal Computer, without any SSH already installed (if SSH is something you install, if you're running a windows 8 client.)

Comment: You can install SSH on Windows.  Depending on how familiar you are with Linux, you could [use cygwin](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/)

Comment: Very simple encryption and decryption: `function xorFF(str) return (str:gsub('.', function(c) return c.char(255-c:byte()) end)) end`

Comment: str:gsub() needs two arguments, Egor, and "." is not a valid variable name, I do believe.

Comment: Well, you can use a simple xor since this is one of the easiest methods, after that you can, if you want, use a substitution method based on a coded rule you implement( ex: Caesar's cypher), etc. search on your favorite engine about cryptography and you will find tons of information both for beginners and for hardcore users. for the offtopic... use the same engine to search for "lua server socket example" and you will have some relevant links there too.

Comment: You can use something like Diffie-Hellman to exchange a shared secret between the two end-points. You can then use that as the secret key(run it through a hash to get the desired bit-length) in a symmetric cipher like AES. If you don't care about encrypting the commands sent, just authenticating, look at using `HMAC-SHA*` as a way to prove the other node knows the secret-key without disclosing. The third way is to use Public key crypto, something like RSA or ECC+ECDSA to do authenication.

Answer (score 1):

> how do you get LuaSocket to reply to the client?

The server obtains the request using `client:receive` and sends its response using `client:send`. Please note that even if the documentation calls the variable "client", it doesn't mean the client side of the connection. Instead it means the "connection to the client" from the server's point of view, returned by `client:accept`.

See http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/old/luasocket-2.0-beta/introduction.html